# Global definition for parameters (typescript or flow)

Tags: typescript, flowtype

Is it possible to have a global type definition for a parameter? Say all my functions (200+) are in the format `myFunction(someParam, arr)`, I want `arr` to always be of type `MyCustomObj`.

The goal is to introduce some quick IDE intellisense to a project where I can't change the source code to include type information.

Comment: You can't change the source code, and you want type information?

Comment: Not unless you're willing to do some smart find and replace, replacing `arr)` (notice the bracket) with `arr: MyType)`,  Once you've done this your intellisense should pick up that `MyType` has not been imported. making the rest of it a bit more straight forward

Comment: @gilamran Yes, I can do it with some elements, parameters are not one of them. It is not suppose to be 'just like typescript', I just want some intellisense in some places where not even a 'class' was used, making it hard to add JSDocs as well.

Comment: @Jay I believe you're right, was hoping to find a way, maybe in Flow. All I need is something of a pattern matching hack for the flow/typescript runtime: whenever you see arr, assume it is of type MyCustomObj

Comment: Can you provide more detail on why you can't just do find and replace for `arr)` -> `arr: SomeType)`? What you're asking for is not possible, but if you provide more information, we can maybe find a creative solution.

Comment: @Adam Because I can't use typescript. Or any other thing that requires an extra step to process JS. It is not my project, I'm just maintaining it.

Comment: If you can't use TypeScript or Flow, then why do you need to declare the type of this thing at all? Let's say we could find a solution, what concrete thing would change so that it helped you?

Comment: If you want to use Flow and just can't add a build step, you can use Flow type comments: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/ . But you'd have to add them to every function, there's no way to have a magic type put on the last argument of every function.

Comment: @Adam 'The goal is to introduce some quick IDE intellisense '. Example: I type "arr." and I get a list of options. Just that would make a huge difference. I know about the comments, still a no go for the team here. I searched really heard about this issue, I realize it might be impossible. I have the feeling that If I would hack the engine, a one line change would give me 80% of the benefits of Typescript/Flow without any changes to the source file, allowing me to unobtrusively introduce it in projects where the team is disagree on the issue.

Comment: The arr in this example is used in 200+ functions as a parameter, and it is a huge object with ~80 top level properties and a deeply nested hierarchy

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not something Flow or TypeScript can do.